# How do I have rbenv and bundler work together without clashing versions in a project?

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv

For a new project, I am forced to use ruby version 2.5.0. Why can I not use other versions of Ruby?

I chose a ruby version with `rbenv local 2.4.0`, but when I type `ruby -v`, I read:

```
ruby 2.5.0dev (2017-08-01 trunk 59456) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

I checked with `bundled env` that the Ruby version is Ruby 2.5.0.

I set my project to require ruby 2.4.0, and I see this message when running `bundle`:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.5.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.0
```

`bundle` is able to install my projects' dependencies but only when the project specifies the ruby version as 2.5.0.

What is going on here? How does one manage and configure different ruby versions with rbenv and bundler? Am I supposed to have different versions of bundler to install each projects respective gems with their corresponding ruby version? Am I missing something with the `gem` cli, which seems to only install bundler with its ruby version set to 2.5.0?

Comment: Try `rbenv global 2.4.0 && rbenv rehash && bundle`, what happens?

Comment: Your first question is fundamentally different from the rest of your question. It should be a separate question, and you should remove that part from here.

Answer (score 0):

Rbenv as rvm provide global setting a ruby version. Otherwise user must specify ruby version every time in every project in its console.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.0(...)

$ rbenv local 2.4.0
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0(...)
```

[Read more about specify ruby version in rbevn](https://makandracards.com/makandra/21545-rbenv-how-to-switch-to-another-ruby-version-temporarily-per-project-or-globally)

If this doesn't work try reinstall rbenv. Before you find answer for this issue for you system, you can use rvm.

So, you can open two console tab and specify two different ruby version in each one. It would work.
When user deploy his project on heroku or with capistrano, that ignore ruby version in his gemfile too. For capistrano we need specify ruby version on capfile or deploy.rb, that should set ruby version in rbenv or rvm every time when you redeploy your project or restart server.